# Poco Logger change Message parameters

Tags: c++, logging, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco::Logger to trace logs in my application.

Now I want to trace a value of a variable in all of my logs. Since I do not want to change every line where I output the line before. I want to make it something default in the format.

I checked the documents and tutorial of Poco logging system, and found:

> - A message can store an arbitrary number of name-value pairs.
> - Names and values can be arbitrary strings.
> - Message parameters can be referenced in a formatter.

which looks like exactly what I'm looking for. But I cannot found detailed information about this and it seems that Poco::logger creates a Poco::Message itself.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the logging framework of POCO. It seems that for [`Poco::Logger::setProperty()`](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Logger.html#17278) _"Only the "channel" and "level" properties are supported"_, which is not what you need. However, you might be able to use [`Poco::Message::set()`](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Message.html#18324) to append the value you want to trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "Poco/Logger.h"
#include "Poco/AutoPtr.h"
#include "Poco/PatternFormatter.h"
#include "Poco/FormattingChannel.h"
#include "Poco/ConsoleChannel.h"
#include "Poco/Message.h"

using namespace Poco;

int main()
{
    Message msg;
    msg.setSource("MySource");
    msg.setText("My message text");
    msg["myParam"] = "My Param";

    AutoPtr<FormattingChannel> pFCConsole = new FormattingChannel(new PatternFormatter("%s: %[myParam], %t"));
    pFCConsole->setChannel(new ConsoleChannel);
    pFCConsole->open();

    Logger& consoleLogger = Logger::root(); // or whatever your logger is
    consoleLogger.setChannel(pFCConsole);
    consoleLogger.log(msg);

    return 0;
}
```

Run:

```
$ ./Logger
MySource: My Param, My message text
```

Only `std::string` custom parameters are currently supported, so you will have to do the conversion if the value is numeric.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that I want to add "myParam" to everywhere I used to log my messages directly using information/warning/error. Is there anyway to do this kind of thing without change every where?

Comment: Yes, of course. I modified the code in the answer to show how. Now, if you want to use error(), information() etc, you will have to wrap the original logger int a class with those methods, and construct the message internally before passing it to the original logger.

Comment: Lot of thanks, problem solved by writing a wrapper class.